# Unable to perform migration using Django and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration

For the project that I have been working on we are using Django as the backend and PostgreSQL as out database. I have already installed all the required files for PostgreSQL and also created a database for the project. I keep on getting the following error when I try to perform migration.
[This is first part of the error after running python3 manage.py migrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AahDY.png)

[This is last part of the error after running python3 manage.py migrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbz71.png)

It says that it is unable to make connection with the port but I don't have any server running. I was using docker to connect the backend with frontend, but I ran docker-compose down command to take down docker. This is how I have setup the database for my project in PostgreSQL (This is the first time I am trying to perform migration in my computer for this project)[Database setup in PostgreSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fui37.png)

[first part of docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOwDO.png)

[second part of docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpkR0.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you're not exposing the right ports of the PostgreSQL container. If you show the docker-compose file content it will help significantly to identify the problem.